# Image re sizing

Tags: resolution, imageresizer

I have an image which 330 px width and 472 px height . I want to plot this image inn to a bigger canvas which is 55% bigger than the current picture .. How can I fount the final image width and height .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a math problem than a programming problem. Let's work on it abstractly to get a formula:

Our variables are:

oldWidth, oldHeight, newWidth, newHeight, percentBigger

The original canvas size is

`oldCanvasSize = oldWidth * oldHeight`

The new canvas size is

`newCanvasSize = newWidth + newHeight`

55% bigger means 155% or 1.55 so

`percent = (percentBigger + 1)`

The new canvas is some percent of the old canvas so we have

`newCanvasSize = percent * oldCanvasSize`

or

`newCanvasSize = (percentBigger + 1) * oldCanvasSize`

I'll assume we want the proportions to stay the same so

`oldWidth / oldHeight = newWidth / newHeight`

By substitution and solving the above equations we get

`newWidth = SquareRoot(percentBigger + 1) * oldWidth`

`newHeight = SquareRoot(percentBigger + 1) * oldHeight`

I'll let the reader plug in the values.